# CURL function for sites with https headings (more than one site)

Tags: php, magento, curl

```
$product_images = $soap->call($session_id, 'catalog_product_attribute_media.list', $product['sku']);
//echo "--".count($product_images)."--";
for($i=0;$i < count($product_images) ;$i++){
    unset($product_images[$i]['file']);
    $curl = curl_init($product_images[$i]['url']);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    $ret_val = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!curl_errno($curl)){
        $file = array(
            'content' => chunk_split(base64_encode($ret_val)),
            'mime' => curl_getinfo($curl , CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE),
        );
        $product_images[$i]['file']=$file;
        $result2 = $soap_2->call($session_id_2,"catalog_product_attribute_media.create", array($result, $product_images[$i]));
    } else {
        print_r(curl_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

This is part of a code that copies all the products from one magneto store to another. The code above copies the images. Now, the code copies all the products without the images, when I debugged to figure out why, I got : `SSL connect error`  I added the "verify = false" but still didnt work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use Magento wrappers and try to use this:

```
$curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
$curl->setConfig(array(
       'verifypeer'   => 0, //this values will be by default, see lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php:75
       'verifyhost'   => 0, 
));
$url = "your_url";
$curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $url, '1.0');
$data = $curl->read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional to :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Try adding this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: Yes "SSL connect error", I tried removing the "s" at https on both sites it work, but I want another way by keeping the s because I dont want my site to be unsecure

Comment: @Serena Try changing SSL version with this line: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 3);`